# React Native module issues

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I have a new react native project which was created with the CLI. I have called it 'mobile' and it seems to have issues with missing modules like `fs`, `crypto`, `util`, etc. I have tried installing the modules manually as other SO posts suggest however it doesn't seem to be working. The iOS simulator says that the module is found but the module specifies a 'main' field that can't be resolved. I can't seem to copy the error message from the simulator though.

Below is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "events": "^3.2.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "querystring": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.1.18",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.16.1",
    "react-native-skeleton-placeholder": "^3.0.2",
    "util": "^0.12.4"
  },
```

My question is how can I resolve the module issue(s) to make it so the app will run in the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Some NPM packages like `fs`, `crypto`, `util` are designed to work in a NodeJs server-side environment. They should not work within React Native.

Comment: Don't think this is it, the code I am using is from guides that are 100% react native so highly doubt that a server-side anything got mixed in.

Comment: Someone mix with NodeJS-specific module like  `"fs": "^0.0.1-security",` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs

Comment: That line is from me using `npm i -s fs` because of the missing module error I got. The ones in `package.json` I did that with are `fs`, `querystring`, `util` and `crypto`. I thought that would fix the issue

Comment: Yeah. Try to remove those packages

Comment: When I do it brings me back to the original error which caused me to install them which is them missing.

Comment: Which package require those dependencies?

Comment: Not sure, it doesn't say what package just that it's missing

Comment: Can you share error traces for that missing packages you are getting